# Knex and Postgress connections

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I created db.js file into my node project

> const environment     = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
>   const configuration   = require('../knexfile')[environment];    var
>   database        = require('knex')(configuration);
>
> module.exports = database;

I call require('xxxxxx/db.js') where I need knex, to make sql query for Postgres database (through different files). It eats my postgres connections (reach 100 pq connections very soon). I checked it with this script code under Postgres database.

> ```
> select
>   sum( numbackends )
> from
>   pg_stat_database;
> ```

What is the best practice to use knex into nodejs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const Knex = require('knex');
const { host, user, password, database, port } = require('settings')
const knex = Knex({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: { host, user, password, database, port },
  pool: { min: 0, max: 200 }
});
```

I suggest to use `Knex.raw(sql, args)` as much as possible. Just because Knex uses the connection pool and release. no need to worry about it.

Hope this will help you somehow.

Comment: Thanks JSX for answer, but it will not help. My settings is practical the same (only max is 10). But it relates to knex connection pool. I have problem with connections toward Postgres DB. I have multi cascade queries which always takes Postgres connection which never release.

Comment: try to use `knex.client.pool.release();`

Comment: knex.client.pool.release() and knex.destroy() are practical the same. It means, I need always to reinstance knex. So each file which use knex needs itself instance of knex module. Any other opinion/help?

Comment: My fault. I had one path into my app, which didn't use knex from my db.js already created always new instance of knex and it eats postgres connections. When I changed code and reused db.js on that place also all works perfect. I noticed, that knex will take one postgres connection for each different path into app. So the default number of postgres connections is 100, so all is ok. JSX thanks for quick help.

Comment: Isn't 200 for max way to much?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    host : '127.0.0.1',
    port : 3306,
    user : 'your_database_user',
    password : 'your_database_password',
    database : 'myapp_test'
  }
});
```

Source - https://knexjs.org/guide/#configuration-options